# Lista de presença php e pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

O que eu estou tentando fazer é que todos as pessoas ligadas ao usuario logado na sessão apareção com uma checkbox para que possa colocar se ele esteve presente ou não e não está aparecendo lá pra eu colocar presença...

check.php

```html
<?php
require_once("db.php");
function check_input($r){
 $r=trim($r);
 $r=strip_tags($r);
 $r=stripslashes($r);
 return $r;
 }

if (isset($_POST['uname'],$_POST['pwd'])){ 
 $u=check_input($_POST['uname']);
 $p=md5(check_input($_POST['pwd']));
 try{
 $db=get_db();
 $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM membros WHERE usuario=? && senha=?");
 $stmt->execute(array($u,$p));
 $r=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if($r){
  session_start();
  $level=$r['level'];
  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $r['usuario'];
  $_SESSION['nome'] = $r['nome'];
     $_SESSION['status'] = $r['status'];
     $_SESSION['foto'] = $r['foto'];
  $_SESSION['level'] = $level;
  if ($level==0){
   header("Location: ../lider/");
   }
  else if($level==1){
   header("Location: ../pastor/");
   }
  }
 else{
  header("Location: ../login.php?err=1");
  }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
  die("Database error: ".$e->getMessage());
 }
}
else{
 header("Location:index.php");
 }
?>
```

pagina de presença

```html
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="checkbox">Lista de Presença</label>
                          
                  <?php
                                    require_once("../cfg/db.php");
                                    $db=get_db();
                                    $stmt = $db-> prepare('SELECT lider,nome FROM membros WHERE lider = $_SESSION['nome']; ORDER BY nome');
                                    $stmt-> execute();
                                    $result = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                   //  print_r($result);
                                    ?>
                  <?php foreach( $result as $row ) { ?> 
               <div class="checkbox-inline1">
                  <label>
                        <input class="minimal" type="checkbox" name="presenca[]" value="<?php echo $row[0]['nome'];?>">  <?php echo $row['nome'];?> 
                  </label>
            </div>                
                  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: não aparece o nome das pessoas com checkbox que selecionou ele como lider, eu acabei de editar porque tinha alguns erros visiveis porem nao funciona ainda...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
<?php
    require_once("../cfg/db.php");
    $db=get_db();
    $nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
    $stmt = $db-> prepare("SELECT lider, nome FROM membros WHERE lider = '$nome' ORDER BY nome");
    $stmt-> execute();
    $result = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //  print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: deu certo, obrigado !